# ReferenceError can't find variable : stylesheet

Tags: javascript, react-native

***I already imported StyleSheet from react-native***

but I got [ReferenceError can't find variable StyleSheet].

I don't know why. Please help me!

I read many stackoverflow posts, they forget to import StyleSheet, View, Text.
But I didn't!!

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-web';

const AddNewStamp = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Header />

  </View>
);

const Header = () => (
  <SafeAreaView style = {styles.HeaderContainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Image 
        source= {'./assets/icon/home_filled.png'}
        style={{ width: 30, heigh: 30}}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Text style={styles.HeaderText}>New Stamp</Text>
  </SafeAreaView>  
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginHorizontal: 10
  },

  HeaderContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-betwween',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  HeaderText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginLeft: 25,
  },
});


export default AddNewStamp;
```

Comment: Your error message and source code don't match up, are you sure this file is the source of the error? In your error you have `stylesheet` in lowercase, such a variable doesn't exist in this file.

Comment: wrong called variable somewhere in your code, `stylesheet` is lowercase should be `StyleSheet`

Comment: ReferenceError can't find variable StyleSheet  /// I'm sorry.

Comment: maybe metro not refreshed or you did forget to import StyleSheet somewhere, try activate debug mode it will give you the file location